# How can I place the object behind eachother?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can I place the lowest diamond shape to look the same as the rest?

Is it possible to add striped patterns?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},on grid]
    

\begin{scope}[
        yshift=-83,every node/.append style={
        yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
        ]
   
    \fill[white,fill opacity=0.9] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
   
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);

   
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=0,every node/.append style={
        yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
                 ]
    \fill[black,fill opacity=.9] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=90,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
                 ]
    \fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=170,every node/.append style={
        yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
      ]
    \fill[white,fill opacity=0.6] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=-170,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
              ]
   
\fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);  

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just draw this diamond first.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},on grid]
 \begin{scope}[
    yshift=-170,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
              ]
   
\fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);  

\end{scope}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9,every node/.style={minimum size=1cm},on grid]
 \begin{scope}[
    yshift=-170,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
              ]
   
\fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);  

\end{scope}   

\begin{scope}[
        yshift=-83,every node/.append style={
        yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
        ]
   
    \fill[white,fill opacity=0.9] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
   
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);

   
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=0,every node/.append style={
        yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
                 ]
    \fill[black,fill opacity=.9] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=90,every node/.append style={
    yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
                 ]
    \fill[gray] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope}
    
\begin{scope}[
    yshift=170,every node/.append style={
        yslant=0.5,xslant=-1},yslant=0.5,xslant=-1
      ]
    \fill[white,fill opacity=0.6] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \draw[black,very thick] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{scope}
    


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```